# combinatorial function c++ using Recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, using

Now this is the combinatorial function if you don't know it:

C(n,k)= {  1                   if k=0 or k = n
           C(n−1,k−1)+C(n−1,k) otherwise

Now, What I really need is to use recursion to print a Pascal's triangle.

Ok,so what I've done so far is this simple recursion function:

```
#include   <iostream>
using namespace std;

int Pas(int r, int c) {
    if (c == 0 || c == r) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return Pas(r - 1, c - 1) + Pas(r - 1, c);
    }
}

int main(){

    cout << Pas(4,2) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Now this function computes perfectly for example:

```
Pas(4,2) = 6
```

But I'm having problem using it to print the whole Pascal's triangle, because I'm new into C++ and especially recursion ..

I'd appreciate any feedback, and I hope that someone would help figure out this problem. But I'd appreciate it more if you guys don't just give me the whole answer (code) just like that; I want to learn.

Thanks!

Comment: Call your function in a loop(s), you should have that covered.

Comment: The recursive function, even when implemented correctly, will be inordinately inefficient, because every non-terminal call generates two new calls: that's exponential. To get a notion about correctness, try to call Pas(2, 4). After correcting the function so that it works, reimplement it using an iterative loop.

Comment: You cannot print the whole Pascal's triangle because it is an infinite series. You can start by making a function that prints the first `n` layers. The function is likely to return `void`.

Comment: That's what I thought about, a loop. But I was afraid it was possible to do it using a recursion only. I think it is kinda impossible to do it without a loop. I'll try that and come ask if I got any other problems. Thanks everyone :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something similar to this might to the job

```
void printTriangle(int printRows, int a = 1, int b = 0)
{
    if (a > printRows) return;
    int val = Pas(a, b);
    cout << val << " ";
    if (a == b) {
        cout << endl;
        printTriangle(printRows, a + 1, 0);
    } else {
        printTriangle(printRows, a, b + 1);
    }
}
```

Running `printTriangle(7)` should print the first 7 rows.

Comment: Thank you. But when I use it it prints the Pascal's triangle upside-down

Comment: @PhpLover1337 Updated.

Comment: Infinite process!  ' cout << val << " "; '

Comment: I think after your if statements the printTriangle(); calling is missing one more value .. Im not sure

Comment: @PhpLover1337 You are correct, I missed to update the function call after the edit. You should be able to get a sense of how recursion works however, even if the example is not 100% correct.

Comment: I get it now you guys are great :D Thanks again.

Comment: I could add another if statement (condition) to print the first row (the first "1")

Comment: @PhpLover1337 You could fix that by changing `int a = 1` to `int a = 0` in the first line.

Comment: Is it possible to print it in a triangle look ? @pingul

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to use your recursive function in a loop, the easiest way would be something like:

```
int n=4; 

for (int i=0; i<=n; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<=i; j++) {
        cout << Pas(i,j)<<" "; 
    }
    cout <<endl; 
}
```

If you want to reinforce the layout, you coud also `#include <iomanip>` and `<limits>` to use a fixed size number output, using the number of digits required to display an integer:  just replace the output statement with:

```
    cout << setw(numeric_limits<int>::digits10+1)<<Pas(i,j);
```

**Edit:**

You could easily build a recursive function to print lines of the triangle:

```
void PrintPas(int r) {
    if (r==1) 
       cout << Pas(1,0); 
    else {
        PrintPas(r-1);
        for (int c=0; c<=r; c++)
           cout << Pas(r,c)<< " ";
    }
    cout <<endl; 
}
```

**Edit 2**

If you want a fully recursive version:

```
void PrintPas(int r, int c) {
    if (r==1) 
       cout << Pas(1,0)<<"  "; 
    else if (c==-1) {
        PrintPas(r-1,r-1);
    }
    else {
        PrintPas(r,c-1); 
        cout << Pas(r,c)<< " ";
    }
    if (r==c)
       cout <<endl; 
}
```

[Online demo](http://ideone.com/rvlZwQ)

Comment: Thanks mate. Is it possible to do it recursively? with no loops needed?

Comment: It's more gymnastics to do a recursive print together with the recursive calculation, because the recursive function would calculate several time the same elements.  But if you do it by line, it's not really a problem.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. Your loop and the recursion version of it, made it easy for me to understand the process. And I appreciate everyone else too. Thank y'all so much :D

Comment: Wow,  impressive! I think we're done here .. you killed it man :D
I really don't know how to thank you ..

Comment: It doesn't print the last two elements. But its helpful .. thanks

Comment: Maybe you could save the intermediate results in a matrix to reduce computation time. For example: once Pas(3,2) has been calculated, then we could save the result and use it to directly compute Pas(4,3) later on. Currently, it will go through the whole Pas(3,2) recursion for both Pas(3,2) and Pas(4,3).

Comment: @CODError I read and learned that recursion takes lots of memory to compute and time too! So for the function above how would you explain what you said (I'm mean code example)

Comment: I am suggesting "Memoization" where you save the results of expensive function calls for later use. You can learn more about this.

Answer (score 1):

[Tail recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) is the recursive equivalent to iterative loops. The following function when called with `sum(0, 5)`

```
int sum(int start, int end, int resultSoFar = 0) {
    if (start == end) return resultSoFar;
    return sum(start + 1, end, resultSoFar + start);
}
```

is equivalent to the iterative function called with `sum(0, 5)`.

```
int sum(int start, int end) {
    int resultSoFar = 0;
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        resultSoFar += i;
    }
    return resultSoFar;
}
```